# Show that the set of invertible $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$ is not connected?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, connectedness

I think I need to work with the determinant of an arbitrary matrix from this family but am not sure.

Comment: This is self-study...

Comment: $\det$ is a continuous map, and $\det: GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a disconinuous range.

Answer (score 0):

$$GL_n(\mathbb R)=\{A\in \mathbb M_{n\times n}:det(A)\not=0\}$$$$=\{A\in \mathbb M_{n\times n}:det(A)<0\}\bigcup\{A\in \mathbb M_{n\times n}:det(A)>0\}$$